# Unable to find the partition intended for Linux on my computer

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, ubuntu-studio

The Ubuntu Studio installer cannot find the disk for it. I can't see it in "KDE Disk". The manager finds only the USB key. When I do the sudo fdisks command in the terminal, it gives me all the disks on my computer, yet it doesn't see the partitions, it and the installer. A partition is however in ext4, but he does not see it. Help me please !

I'm French, but I didn't dare to put my question in French, because the site is English. So I took google translation so as not to be mistaken in English, and please don't judge.

I accept anything that can help me except a full disk format. I can format the partition, but not the disk. See you !

Comment: Not sure how active this is: https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/ Have you updated UEFI, turned off UEFI Secure Boot, in Windows turned off fast start up & bitlocker? If SSD, it may also need firmware update. What brand/model system?

Comment: You mention Ubuntu Studio *installer* which is very vague..  Ubuntu Studio has different installers depending on release details; which you've not told us. Recent releases have used the `calamares` installer (older releases using `ubiquity`) so please be specific. The current `calamares` has improved of late; but again without release details your answer may be using a later version available for the same release (*you gave no details so I don't know if this is possible for you! but some releases have more than a single version*).  Please provide specific details.

Comment: My version of Ubuntu Studio is 22.04 LTS. My PC is an Acer, but there is no update available.

Acer Aspire A515-55 Intel Core i7 8GB RAM
Windows Version: 11
RST: Yes
Driver: No update available
USB key: 32 GB (as a reminder, the system only sees it

I don't really understand the version. My Ubuntu Studio, I installed the latest version on the USB key, 22.04 LTS. On the site, I saw a download button, as anyone I clicked on it. Hope that helps you.

Comment: I don't have UEFI. My PC use EFI.

Comment: I looked at my version of Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS Install, and saw Calamares - System Installer. Thank you for answering me so quickly!

Comment: uEFI is EFI (*the original u='universal' now mostly not used*)...  Are you using 22.04? 22.04.1? or 22.04.2? media as they each have different `calamares` on them & thus if using older Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS media the `calamares` & other packages can be updated.